Relationship between AUC and Cross-entropy
I understand that AUC measures the model's ability to rank the subjects (see Why is ROC AUC equivalent to the probability that two randomly-selected samples are correctly ranked?).
In contrast, binary cross-entropy (or log loss) measures the calibration of predicted probabilities.
Based on this distinction, optimizing one metric (e.g., cross-entropy) does not necessarily lead to an optimal result in terms of the other metric (e.g., AUC). However, many models use cross-entropy as the main objective function and still achieve decent/great AUC scores. Furthermore, when cross-entropy loss is minimized—meaning the predicted probabilities are 1 for positive samples and 0 for negative samples—the AUC is also optimal.
Therefore, my questions are

Can the cross-entropy loss be partially decomposed into a ranking component?
Do cross-entropy and AUC exhibit some degree of correlation?


YES(ish)
Cross-entropy loss (XEnt) is a strictly proper scoring rule. While the decomposition of the Brier score (basically square loss) is the most famous, every strictly proper scoring rule can be decomposed into a measure of calibration and a measure of discrimination. This seems to have been shown by Bröcker (2009).
ROCAUC is exactly a measure of discrimination: how different are the predictions for different observations. In that sense, yes, there is some overlap between what is measured by XEnt and by ROCAUC. "Correlation" is a dicey term to use, since there is a technical meaning in statistics that does not perfectly align with what the word means in colloquial English, but there certainly is a relationship between XEnt and ROCAUC.
REFERENCE
Bröcker, Jochen. "Reliability, sufficiency, and the decomposition of proper scores." Quarterly Journal of the Royal Meteorological Society: A journal of the atmospheric sciences, applied meteorology and physical oceanography 135.643 (2009): 1512-1519.

In addition to @Dave's answer (+1).
I recently have come across the paper Understanding the Role of Cross-Entropy Loss in Fairly Evaluating Large Language Model-based Recommendation by Xu et al. There one of their main results is that: "minimizing cross-entropy is equivalent to maximizing a lower bound of Normalized Discounted Cumulative Gain (NDCG) and Reciprocal Rank (RR)".
Using the paper's notation:
Assuming a scoring (i.e. relevance) function $s$, cross-entropy forces the model to differentiate the target item $v_+$ from other $v$ items by increasing the predicted score of it $s(v_+)$. But by assigning a higher score to $s(v_+)$ for being a relevant item, it implicitly has to improve its rank $r_+$ as the rank itself defined as $r_+ := |{v \in I : s(v) \geq s({v_+})}|$ with $I$ being the set of all items.
(Granted, because usually ranking measures as NDCG and RR are defined up based on a number of retrieved items $k$ so we have NDCG@k, items ranked $r_+ >k$ become irrelevant as they do not as they contribute to the NDCG@k calculations. That is one of the reasons why in the paper there is work done with a truncated loss - the authors explore this point more.)
So to revisit the original points:

Yes, cross-entropy as a clear ranking aspect to it.
Yes, as ultimately cross-entropy will relate with any ranking metric because it implicitly makes "more relevant items rank higher" as itself gets minimised.

